# Specialized partialization with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class ,`MyClass<class E,class T>`,and i want to use  :

`std::unary_function<T,bool> _predicate`;
`std::binary_function<T,E,void> _swaper`;

as template template parameters in my class , notice the bool and the void which is partial template specialization ....

can someone tell how `MyClass` decleration and ctor that should take predicate and swaper as arguments should look like  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends if you need to use the parameters only in the constructor or not. Could be:

```
class MyClass
{
    template <class T, class E>
    MyClass(std::unary_function<T,bool> p, std::binary_function<T,E,void> s)
    {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

or

```
template <class T, class E>
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(std::unary_function<T,bool> p, std::binary_function<T,E,void> s)
    {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: this is exactly as i've tried but it seems not to work and again you miss the issue of template template arguments... you need to declare it in other way : template <class T,class E> is not enough if you have template template arguments like unary_function and binary_function....

Comment: can you please add a full sample of what you have done and what is not working?

Comment: one important thing: the code I posted is perfectly valid but assumes that the type of the first argument (the only one for unary_function) is the same. If not, you need a third template parameter. Also note that if you use the second version of the code (template class) you will need to provide the template arguments on instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

i've just figured it out ...
there is no use of ctor like:

```
MyClass(std::unary_function<T,bool> p, std::binary_function<T,E,void> s)
```

**the std::unary_function is just a struct decleration** it does not contain operator() and ofcourse not a virtual operator() , thus it has no use as an argument in a function...

this is how it supposed to look like :

```
template <class T, class E,class PredicateFunctionUnaryOperator,class SwapFunctionBinaryOperator> 
class MyClass
{
private:
    PredicateFunctionUnaryOperator _p;
    SwapFunctionBinaryOperator _s;
    T _arg1;
    E _arg2;
public:
    MyClass(PredicateFunctionUnaryOperator p, SwapFunctionBinaryOperator s,T arg1,E arg2): _p(p),_s(s)
    {
        _arg1 = arg1;
        _arg2 = arg2;
    }
    void f()
    {
        std::cout<<"Unary Function output is :"<<_p(_arg1)<<endl;;
        std::cout<<"Binary Function Output is:"<<_s(_arg1,_arg2);


        std::cout<<"Chauoo!!"<<endl;
    }
};
```

but as i can see its working i cant understand when is the special syntax template decleration that is related with "template template parameters" is used...

Thanks.